# Typescript error in react-redux: "super calls are not permitted outside constructors or in nested functions inside constructors"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I get the typescript error "Super calls are not permitted outside constructors or in nested functions inside constructors.ts(2337)" in *any* redux-connected component. This is a minimal example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { AppState } from './types';

interface StateProps {
  someProp: string;
}

class MyConnectedComponent extends React.Component<StateProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: StateProps) {
    super(props); // ts error here: Super calls are not permitted outside constructors or in nested functions inside constructors.ts(2337)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state: AppState): StateProps {
  return {
    someProp: '',
  };
};

export default connect<StateProps>(mapStateToProps)(MyConnectedComponent);
```

The error disappears if I don't connect the component to Redux but simply export the class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake: contructor ... should be constructor

Comment: @rrd thanks - fixed. That's not the issue though.

Comment: If you don't cast the connect, (i.e., remove <StateProps>) does the same error occur?

Comment: I put the code above into a test react/redux project and it worked fine. What versions of everything are you using? I also wonder if the problem maybe isn't in the code you've posted, but somewhere else, e.g. maybe where you're setting up the store or middleware or something?

Comment: @rrd - yes, same problem without the generic parameter.

Comment: @YoniGibbs - the component above does not reference anything except AppState, and I can remove that by replacing AppState with {}, and the problem is still there. This is a new project so everything is latest versions. Interesting that you don't see it. Maybe it's something to do with my linting setup. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

As [@rrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4627262/rrd) answered in the comment section, there is misspelling mistake,
turn `contructor` to `constructor` and it will fix